# What is the maximam distance of light that is released by a flashlight?

Tags: visible-light, atmospheric-science

Recently I looked at the cloudy night sky and noticed a pale green color light moving around the clouds for about 20 min.After observation I came a conclusion that it is probably because of a light house near by or any powerful light emitter.I could even barely see the light is being flashed from ground to clouds.Then I thought,If I focus my flashlight in to the night sky  what would be the farthest distance of the light can reach?

Comment: As long as the photons are not absorbed by anything along its path, they will continue on forever.

Comment: This might be interesting to you: http://what-if.xkcd.com/13/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Infinity as long as you have a detector strong enough to detect it. Light keeps on travelling in a straight line forever as long as it doesn't bounce off some object.

The problem with the lights you are talking about is that their intensity is really low and you can't resolve them because of the other stronger sources of lights you have around yourself. Human eyes can resolve a very small number of photons ( in the order of 3-4!!) so you would be able to see any source of light in appropriate conditions.

Comment: Do you have the source for that number of photons an eye can resolve?

Comment: http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Quantum/see_a_photon.html
or
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_threshold

even though the first says 1 photon the second one 90 photons. I was told 3-4. But the point is that it is a really small number! It probably also depend on the wavelength : it may be that human eyes are sensitive to certain wavelengths more than others.

Comment: Nice links. Have a +1!

Answer (score 1):

If you know when to expect it, light can be detected at the single photon level. For very long distances, the expected photon flux  will be less than one per detector per unit time of your choice. Go look up the Lunar Laser Ranging Experiment, in which light was detected at this level.  Also, the Lunar Laser Communication Demonstration, which allows high bandwidth as low power levels.